# Javascript: How to display a div at the place of another div on the click of a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the given example, what I want for the `#rightdiv` is that initially the `#rightdivOne` should be displayed in the `#rightdiv` and `#rightdivTwo` or `#rightdivThree` should not be displayed, then on the click of the `submit` button, `#rightdivTwo` should be displayed in the place of the `#rightdivOne` (so that `#rightdivOne` is no more visible), and then again on the click of the `submit` button, `#rightdivThree` is displayed in the same place.

The rest of the page should remain static.

**Is it possible to do this through Javascript only? I can't use AJAX. Moreover, I don't prefer to use JQuery and will only use it as a last resort. 
If this is possible, can somebody guide me a bit about how?**

**[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/96xw2af7/)**

```
<div id="leftrightdiv" style="width:380px; padding-left:10px; padding-right:10px; background-color:grey; height:400px;">
    <div id="leftdiv" style="width:190px; float:left; overflow:auto; background-color:#7bbe7b; height:400px;"></div>

    <div id="rightdiv" style="width:190px; float:right;  overflow:auto; background-color:#87ccd1; height:400px;">
        <div id="rightdivOne" style="width:100%; float:right; background-color:#25dcea; height:400px;">
            <p>I am the statement of the question. I am the statement of the question. I am the statement of the question. I am the statement of the question. </p>
            <div><input type="radio" name="radiorightdivTwo" value="Option One">
            <label>Option One</label></div>
            <div><input type="radio" name="radiorightdivTwo" value="Option Two">
            <label>Option Two</label></div>
            <div><input type="radio" name="radiorightdivTwo" value="Option Three">
            <label>Option Three</label></div>
            <div><input type="radio" name="radiorightdivTwo" value="Option Four">
            <label>Option Four</label></div>
            <span style="float:right; margin:50px;"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></span>
        </div>
        <div id="rightdivTwo" style="width:100%; float:right; background-color:#d1879b; height:400px;">
            <p>I am the statement of the question. I am the statement of the question. I am the statement of the question. I am the statement of the question. </p>
            <div><input type="radio" name="radiorightdivTwo" value="Option One">
            <label>Option One</label></div>
            <div><input type="radio" name="radiorightdivTwo" value="Option Two">
            <label>Option Two</label></div>
            <div><input type="radio" name="radiorightdivTwo" value="Option Three">
            <label>Option Three</label></div>
            <div><input type="radio" name="radiorightdivTwo" value="Option Four">
            <label>Option Four</label></div>
            <span style="float:right; margin:50px;"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></span>
        </div>
        <div id="rightdivThree" style="width:100%; float:right; background-color:#8f63f2; height:400px;">
            <p>I am the statement of the question. I am the statement of the question. I am the statement of the question. I am the statement of the question. </p>
            <div><input type="radio" name="radiorightdivTwo" value="Option One">
            <label>Option One</label></div>
            <div><input type="radio" name="radiorightdivTwo" value="Option Two">
            <label>Option Two</label></div>
            <div><input type="radio" name="radiorightdivTwo" value="Option Three">
            <label>Option Three</label></div>
            <div><input type="radio" name="radiorightdivTwo" value="Option Four">
            <label>Option Four</label></div>
            <span style="float:right; margin:50px;"><input type="submit" value="Submit"></span>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Note:- I am using inline CSS for a reason. So please don't ground me on that.

Comment: Please show us your attempted javascript and let us know what went wrong.

Comment: @showdev I did not attempt anything. I have no clue how to do and what to do. So if somebody can give me a clue like, you can do this by using this and then doing that, I can write some JS code, and Google something as well.

Comment: @showdev I just know that it could be done in Java using a card layout, so it must be possible in a web application as well (and I have seen applications with dynamic content), so there must be a way. I need to know what that way is.

Comment: @Downvoter:- Please tell me the reason of the downvote.

Comment: ["This question does not show any research effort"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223480/to-flag-or-not-to-flag-question-that-dont-show-own-effort#223482). No offense intended.

Comment: @showdev I have to agree here. I will improve this, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this with simple vanilla js and even do your onclick event inline (unless you want to add unique IDs to each of your submit buttons then you could use event listeners): [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/96xw2af7/6/)

```
// here is the javascript function to change elements
function nextPg(oldpage, newpage) {
     document.getElementById(oldpage).style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById(newpage).style.display = "block";
}

// add the following to the submit button html
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="nextPg('rightdivOne','rightdivTwo');">

// and lastly, each subsequent 'page' needs to start out with 'display: none;' style
<div id="rightdivTwo" style="width:100%; float:right; background-color:#d1879b; height:400px; display: none;">
```

Answer (score 1):

I've just created a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/96xw2af7/1/) you can work with:

```
 $("input[type='submit']").click(function () {
  if ($("#rightdivOne").is(':visible')) {
    $("#rightdivOne").fadeOut('fast', function () {
        $('#rightdivTwo').fadeIn('fast');
    });
   }
   else
   {
    $("#rightdivTwo").fadeOut('fast', function () {
        $('#rightdivThree').fadeIn('fast');

    });
 }
});
```

I guess in the next step you would like to check which div is selected using the radio-buttons, and change to the selected div when submit is clicked. For now this is just replacing the current div with the next one as requested as kind of example you can start with. Though you mentioned that you would prefer a pure Javascript solution and jQuery as a last option only - it was just done faster with jQuery, I could add the same in Javascript. As I noticed that the divs that should be displayed had the same copy before testing the js, I've just added 1st, 2nd and 3rd to the html (only adjustment), but the change of colour probably is indicator enough that the divs get replaced.

Comment: Only the copy in the divs (added 1st, 2nd, 3rd) to indicate that the divs get replaced.

Comment: "I could add the same in Javascript", Can this be done without JQuery?

Comment: Yes, it will only take some more lines to write. In short - jQuery is only a Javascript framework / library, so it basically consists of javascript and just defines easy to use functions / options to make one's life easier.

Comment: I am using Moodle. Their official JS library is YUI. So JQuery can present some problems. While the code is pretty understandable, I would prefer to use JS only

Comment: Ok, so you have good reasons. Noticed that there was already a pure js approach posted as answer some mins ago, so I won't edit / extend my example as you already have a pure js solution provided now.